# How to organise a date in 3 different columns in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a lot of climatic data organise by dates like this.

```
df = data.frame(date = c("2011-03-24", "2011-02-03", "2011-01-02"), Precipitation = c(20, 22, 23))
```

And I want to organise it like this one

```
df = data.frame(year = c("2011", "2011","2011"), month = c("03","02","01"), day = c("24", "03", "02"), pp = c(20, 22, 23))
```

I have a lot of information and I can not do it manually.

Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using strsplit you can do like this way:

**Logic**: strsplit will split the date with dashes to create list of 3 elements each having 3 parts of year, month and day. We bind these elements using rbind but to do it iteratively. We use do.call, So do.call will row bind these list elements into 3 rows. Since the outcome is a matrix, we convert it into a dataframe and then using setNames we give new names to the columns. The last cbind will bind these 3x3 dataframe with original precipitation.

```
cbind(setNames(data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(df$date, '-'))), c('Year', 'month', 'day')), 'Precipitation' = df$Precipitation)
```

**Output**:

```
 Year month day Precipitation
1 2011    03  24            20
2 2011    02  03            22
3 2011    01  02            23
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns integer values for year, month, and day. If you really need them as characters padded with `0` you can use `formatC(x, width = 2, flag = "0")` on the result.

```r
library(clock)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  date = c("2011-03-24", "2011-02-03", "2011-01-02"), 
  pp = c(20, 22, 23)
)

df %>%
  mutate(
    date = as.Date(date),
    year = get_year(date),
    month = get_month(date),
    day = get_day(date)
  )
#>         date pp year month day
#> 1 2011-03-24 20 2011     3  24
#> 2 2011-02-03 22 2011     2   3
#> 3 2011-01-02 23 2011     1   2
```